# Oracle update command return always 0 in c#

Tags: c#, oracle

For the past few hours I am trying to update my oracle table but OracleCommand returns 0 always . Any help would be appreciated.

```
 string strConnection = @"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP) 
 (HOST=localhost)(PORT=##))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=###)));" +
                              "User Id = ###; Password = ###;";
 using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(strConnection))
 {
    char quote = '"';
    string strCommand = @"update test set " + quote +"ID"+quote+"=:id," + 
    quote + "NAME" + quote + "=:name where " + quote + "AGE" + quote +        
    "=:age";
     OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(strCommand,connection);
     command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("id", "32"));
     command.Parameters.Add( new OracleParameter("name", "Justin"));
     command.Parameters.Add( new OracleParameter("age", "95"));
     connection.Open();
     int res = command.ExecuteNonQuery(); /// 0 always
     Console.WriteLine("Result = " + res.ToString());
     Console.ReadKey();
  }
```

Comment: And what if you call the same SQL inside oracle?

Comment: Why wrapping quotes around every column names? Just use `UPDATE test SET ID = :id, NAME = :name WHERE AGE = :age`. Zero value after `ExecuteNonQuery` indicates no data was updated.

Comment: You right i do not need to wrap with quotes my query and i solved my problem by stop and start oracle server. Thank you